# Read csv file for datadriven testing in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am currently trying to do some datadriven testing with robot framework from a csv file, using a python customlibrary. I am running in some problems though, would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction
This is the error I am getting:

> Resolving variable '${Tlogdata.0}' failed: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

The csv I want to process currently has two records (I tried without, with single, and double codes):

```
1-KR8P27,11.0,1000
1-KR8P27,12.0,1001
```

I suspect the problem is with the customlibrary. I tried a lot in tweaking my code, but with what I found and my Python knowledge (that is admittably very basic) I cannot find any issue. This is what I currently have:

```
import csv


def read_csv_file(filename):
data = []
with open(filename,) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
return data
```

I am using some more keywords in Robot Framework to use this customlibrary to fetch data from my csv. While I suspect that my python code is the problem and I double checked everything I might be overlooking something here instead:

In a datamanager keyword file I created the following Keyword:

```
 Get CSV Data
  [Arguments]  ${FilePath}
  ${Data} =  read csv file  ${FilePath}
  [Return]  ${Data}
```

Than I created a 'looping' keyword with a for loop:

```
Check multiple results
[Arguments]    ${tlogdatas}
FOR    ${tlogdata}    IN    ${tlogdatas}
    Check result TLOG3    ${tlogdata}
```

The keyword I call in my loop is already used in a testcase without a datadriven setup, and works. Only the variables are named differently to make it work with the datadriven thing. The keyword looks like this:

```
Check result TLOG3
  [Arguments]    ${Tlogdata}
  ${queryResults} =    query       select x_ord_pts_earn, total_amt from siebel.s_order where 
  contact_id = ${Tlogdata.0} and total_amt = ${Tlogdata.1}    and X_ORD_PTS_earn = ${Tlogdata.2}
  # log     @{queryResults[0][1]}
   ${dbvalue} =    set variable    ${queryResults}
   ${DB ordptsearn} =    set variable    ${queryResults[0][0]}
   ${DB contact_id} =    set variable    ${queryResults[0][1]}
   should be equal as integers     ${DB ordptsearn}     ${Tlogdata.2}
   should be equal as strings      ${DB contact_id}     ${Tlogdata.1}
    END
```

Than in my testcase I define a variable which fetches its results from my datamanager keyword and use the  looping keyword to go through the csv values:

```
Check TLOG results from CSVFile
${Tlogdata} =    DataManager.Get CSV Data    ${TLOG_RESULTS_CSVPath}
 TLOG.Check multiple results    ${Tlogdata}
```

It might also be worth it to show the values from the csv that are fetched according to the report file:

```
${Tlogdata} = [["'1-KR8P27'", "'11.0'", "'1000'"], ["'1-KR8P27'", "'12.0'", "'1001'"]]
```

I hope this is somewhat clear, I understand it is quit some text. But I am not 100% sure where the problem is in my scripts. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing your list wrong. Instead of `${Tlogdata.0}` you should have `${Tlogdata[0]}`, etc..

Here is a quick example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${Tlogdata}=    Evaluate    [["'1-KR8P27'", "'11.0'", "'1000'"], ["'1-KR8P27'", "'12.0'", "'1001'"]]
    Log    ${Tlogdata[0]}
    Log    ${Tlogdata[1]}
    Log    ${Tlogdata[0][1]}
    Log    ${Tlogdata[1][1]}
```